# ExperienceBundle: missing property renderPriority

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, community-cloud, experience-bundle

I retrieved a ExperienceBundle and all the necessary dependencies from a sandbox and am trying to deploy to production. I keep having to manually add this `renderPriority` for a themed community. It looks like it was not brought over for the theme .json files. There are a lot that I've added and I'm still manually adding some. It just seems like maybe I missed a config setting and that's why it didn't pull over.

Additionally, it doesn't look like `renderPriority` is even a field on theme files: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm

Error:

> You seem to be missing the property renderPriority in Themed_Demo/themes/webster.json

Comment: `renderPriority` is in the `views` files, not the themes (looking at my own experience bundle and the documentation you linked). That documentation mentions a setting `progressive rendering`, is that turned on?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Good thought but it is false. I agree, it's not on the themes in documentation or when I retrieved from sandbox but sfdx made me add it to the themes files because the deploy failed. In fairness, it did the same thing for my view files. I've added it to both files and am getting runtime errors on a managedpackage so I think that fixed it but I guess maybe it's still just because it's a pilot feature that I'm struggling with it?

Comment: It could very well be something undocumented or an issue. I would put in a support case if you're able to go through that. I haven't had to deploy from a sandbox to production yet since enabling this metadata type so I can't confirm I get the same error message.

Comment: could be API version related?